# jsonp data is being returned as undefined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp, feed

i am trying to build a stock feed using jsonp so it will work in an browser and i don't have to worry about the cross domain issues.

i built a weather feed using the exact same code, so i believe the issue is with the data.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.ajax({
url : "http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=SO",
dataType : "jsonp",
success : function(parsed_json) {
var symbol= parsed_json['t'];


var stockComplete;
stockComplete = symbol;

document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = stockComplete;

}
});



});


</script>
```

i believe the data coming in is json and not jsonp. is there a way to convert tit? the weather data is a .json file so i am trying to understand if they are different and how to make the code work with this different data type.

stock: http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=SO

weather: http://api.wunderground.com/api/796084cae7d5f94e/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/30308.json

any advice is most appreciated, if there is a stock feed out there that delivers jsonp maybe that would be the easiest, but most don't differentiate between the 2.

Comment: *is there a way to convert it* ...No. You can't force an API to send jsonp if it is not set up for it

Comment: am i correct in the assumption that the code is not working because the stock feed is coming in as json and not jsonp?